# Stochastic integral and $\lambda^2$, $\lambda^2_\text{loc}$

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I know that the Brownian motion is in $\lambda^2_\text{loc}$(namely the integrand $\phi$ is progressive and for every $t$, $\int_0^t \phi_s^2\,ds< \infty$), however, for every $t > 0$ it is in $\lambda^2(t)$ (the integrand is progressive and $\operatorname E\left[\int_0^t\phi_s^2\,ds \right] < \infty$)  and finally that the B.M. it is not in $\lambda^2$ $\big(E\left[\int_0^\infty\phi_s^2\,ds \right] < \infty\big)$.

Therefore if I have a stochastic integral as the following:
$$\int_0^tB_s\,dB_s$$
in this case is $B_s$ in $\lambda^2(t)$ because the interval of the integral is only on $[0,t]$, and so is sufficient only checking that $E\left[\int_0^t\phi_s^2\,ds \right] < \infty$, and not also that $E\left[\int_0^\infty\phi_s^2\,ds \right] < \infty$, right?.
However, if I have $$\int_0^\infty B_s \, dB_s$$ in this case instead $B_s$ (the integrand) is in $\lambda^2_\text{loc}$ because I have the integral up to $\infty$. Is it right this distinction?

I would really appreaciate a feedback

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I do not fully understand what you are asking...but nevertheless, I will try to clear things up a bit.

Following your notation, I write

- $\lambda^2$ for the progressively measurable functions $\phi$ such that $\mathbb{E}\int_0^{\infty} \phi(s)^2 \, ds < \infty$,
- $\lambda^2(t)$ for the progressively measurable functions $\phi$ such that $\mathbb{E}\int_0^t \phi(s)^2 \, ds < \infty$
- $\lambda^2_{\text{loc}}$ for the progressively measurable functions $\phi$ such that $\int_0^t \phi(s)^2 \, ds < \infty$ a.s. for each $t \geq 0$.

Then $$\lambda^2 \subseteq \bigcap_{t \geq 0} \lambda^2(t) \subseteq \lambda^2_{\text{loc}}. \tag{1}$$

**Example 1:** Consider $$\int_0^{\infty} B_s \, dB_s,$$ i.e. $\phi(s)=B_s 1_{[0,\infty)}(s)$. Then $\phi \notin \lambda^2$ since $\mathbb{E}\int_0^{\infty} B_s^2 \,d s = \int_0^{\infty} s \, ds=\infty$. However, $\phi \in \lambda^2(t)$ for each $t \geq 0$, and so, by $(1)$, $\phi \in \lambda^2_{\text{loc}}$.

**Example 2:** Consider for fixed $T>0$  $$\int_0^T B_s \, dB_s,$$ i.e. $\phi(s)=B_s 1_{[0,T]}(s)$. Then $\phi \in \lambda^2$ since $$\mathbb{E}\int_0^{\infty} \phi(s)^2 \, ds = \mathbb{E}\int_0^T B_s^2 \, ds = T < \infty.$$ In particular, $\phi \in \bigcap_{t \geq 0} \lambda^2(t)$ and $\phi \in \lambda^2_{\text{loc}}$.

Comment: Okey, so in the Example 1 could I conclude that the stochastic integral is a martingale? I guess that it is not because, although it is in $\lambda^2(t)$ for each t, it is not in $\lambda^2$ (and for concluding that it is a martingale i should have that $\phi \in \lambda^2$, because the stochastic integral is defined in $[0,\infty]$), right? While instead in example 2, it is a martingale.

Comment: @Alias__ What do you mean by the stochastic integral being a martingale? The stochastic integral $\int_0^{\infty} B_s \, dB_s$ is just a random variable. Of course, you can set $M_t := \int_0^{\infty} B_s \, dB_s$ (i.e. $M$ is a constant process) and then $(M_t)_{t \geq 0}$ fails to be a martingale because it is not integrable.

Comment: I know that if $\phi \in \lambda^2$, then there exists $M=(M_t)_{t\in \mathbb R} \in H^2_C$ (square integrable martingale) s.t. for all t larger than 0: $M_t=\int_0^t \phi_sdB_s$ a.s. .. What I'm asking is: if  $\phi \in \lambda^2(T)$ instead that of $\phi \in \lambda^2$ does the previous statement still hold? if not, what does it change?

Comment: @Alias__ The process $M_t = \int_0^t \phi_s \, dB_s$ is a martingale if $\phi \in \lambda^2(t)$ for all $t \geq 0$. If $\phi \in \lambda^2(t)$ for some $t<T$ but $\phi \notin \lambda^2(T)$, then $(M_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is not a martingale since $M_T$ fails to be integrable.

Comment: and if i have $B=(B_t)_{t \in[0,T]}$ (a $(\mathcal F_t)_{t \in[0,T]}$-brownian motion), and i have $\int_0^T B_s dB_s$ is it  enough that $\phi_s=B_s \in \lambda^2(T)$ for being a martingale?

Comment: @Alias__ Well, yes..