# Ito's Isometry and integrands in $\lambda^2_{\text{loc}}$

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Does the Ito isometry
$$E\left[\left(\int_0^t\phi_s \, dB_s\right)^2\right]=E\left[\int_0^t(\phi_s)^2 \, ds\right]$$ hold also when $\phi$ in $\lambda^2_{\text loc}$ (namely the integrand $\phi$ is progressive and for every $t$, $\int_0^t \phi_s^2\,ds< \infty$) (the larger class of integrands)?

Comment: Yes it does. $\phi \in \lambda_{loc}^{2}$ implies $\phi \in L^{2}[0,t]$.

Comment: Why it hold? $\phi \in \lambda^2_{\text loc}$ mean that for each t $\int_0^t\phi^2_sds < \infty$ why this imply that $E\big[(\int_0^t\phi^2_sds)^2\big] < \infty$? $2)$ i know that $B_t$ (B.M.) is in $\lambda^2(t)$ for each t, but that $B_t$ is not in $\lambda^2$ but in $\lambda^2_{loc}$. So if i have $\int_0^tB_sdBs$ this $B_s$ is in $\lambda^2(t)$ because the integral is up to $t$. But in $\int_0^{\infty}B_sdBs$  $B_s$ is in $\lambda^2_{loc}$ because the integral is up to $\infty$. is right?

Comment: The notation $\lambda^2_{\text{loc}}$ is not standard...for the understanding of the question, it would be helpful if you could add the definition to the body of your question.

Comment: I modified it. @saz could you give a look also to this mine question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3494471/stochastic-integral-and-lambda2-lambda2-textloc? is the same that i did here in the comment. Is a big doubt for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Itô's isometry holds for locally square integrable functions. Take a progressively measurable function $\phi$ such that $\int_0^t \phi(s)^2 \, ds < \infty$ and define stopping times by

$$\sigma_n := \inf\{t>0; \int_0^t \phi(s)^2 \, ds \geq n\}.$$

From $$\sigma_n(\omega)>t \iff \int_0^t \phi(s,\omega)^2 \, ds < n$$ we find that $\phi_n(t) := \phi (t) \cdot 1_{[0,\sigma_n)}(t)$ satisfies $$\mathbb{E} \int_0^t \phi_n(s)^2 \, ds \leq n$$ for all $t \geq 0$. Hence, $\phi_n \in L^2$ and, by Itô's isometry, $$\mathbb{E} \left| \int_0^t \phi_n(s) \, dB_s \right|^2 = \mathbb{E} \int_0^t \phi_n(s)^2 \, ds<\infty.\tag{1}$$ Moreover, by the definition of the Itô integral for locally square integrable functions, the identity $$\int_0^t \phi(s) \, dB_s = \int_0^t \phi_n(s) \, dB_s$$ holds on $\{t \leq \sigma_n\}$. Since $\sigma_n \uparrow \infty$, this means that $$\int_0^t \phi(s) \, dB_s = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \int_0^t \phi_n \, dB_s. \tag{2}$$ Applying the monotone convergence theorem (MCT), we get

\begin{align*} \mathbb{E} \left| \int_0^t \phi(s) \, dB_s \right|^2& \stackrel{\text{MCT}}{=} \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{E} \left| \int_0^t \phi_n(s) \, dB_s \right|^2 \\ &\stackrel{(1)}{=} \mathbb{E} \int_0^t \phi_n(s)^2 \, ds \\ &\stackrel{\text{MCT}}{=} \mathbb{E} \int_0^t \phi(s)^2 \,ds, \end{align*} where we used in the last step that $\phi_n \uparrow \phi$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: I think that you have used the positiveness of the integral of the right-hand side of (2). Is it correct?

Comment: According to the following Q&A, it has a counterexample. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1296225/ito-isometry-for-bounded-ito-integral